# are they going to make the 4th movie of transformers

Tags: transformers

I have seen pics of it but when i went to youtube and saw the trailer of it.But it was just scenes of the other three movies.are they even going to make a fourth or not?

Comment: The simple answer to your yes/no question is... "yes." http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2109248/

Comment: I find the timing of this question amusing as just this morning, a co-worker was held up in traffic caused by the filming of this movie.

Comment: Speculation about whether future works of fiction will be filmed/written is off-topic here.

Comment: @AndresF. Normally, I would agree with you, but it's not at all speculation. They've been filming for a while now.

Answer (score 2):

[Transformers: Age of Extinction](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2109248/combined) is set for a June 27, 2014 release. The director is the same, but almost no cast members are reprising their roles (unless in a possible cameo form). We do know that Peter Cullen will again be the voice of Optimus Prime.

It should be noted there is also a poster with a [10.07.14](http://teaser-trailer.com/movie/transformers-4/) release date.